# Web Essentials settings error and its setting for LESS

Tags: asp.net, web-essentials

I have installed VS2013 installed on my computer. I also installed

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC

and

Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2 RC

successfully. Now when I work on a website project,  go to WEBESSENTIALS top menu, and select create solution settings, I get the following error message:

```
Path cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Also, I want use the LESS feature of web essentials. Can anybody tell me how?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working on a Web Site without a Solution file? I received the same error message as you, but fixed this by creating a solution and Adding Existing Website.

Comment: You are right. I just created a website project. VS2013 did not create any solution. Thanks for chiming in. I will give it a try. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add a solution to your project to create a Web Essentials solution settings file. If your project (Web Site) doesn't have a solution, I'm guessing there's no solution to apply settings to.

What I do is create a New Empty Project, then add a New Web Site... or Existing Web Site.. to the solution.

It seems in my experiences that when I use 'File > Open Website', it creates a temporary solution, but Web Essentials doesn't seem to use this for its solutions settings.

Comment: Hi jtlowe, I did what you said and the error is gone. Do you happen to  have any pointer that show me how to set Web Essentials's LESS target directory?

Comment: It there's a setting for this in Web Essentials 2013 for VS 2013. I'm using VS 2012 and I don't think WE 2012 has this feature. I've been using a program called Prepros to handle all of my less compiling/output. It lets me have settings per less file and other handy things. It might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the targeted project in your solution & "set as startup project."